# I have a list, I want to search all the words online instantaneously and simulataneously

Tags: search, browser, search-engine

I have a list. e.g.

1. ride
2. prediction
3. pottery
4. virgin
5. decisive
6. legislation
7. core
8. past
9. sympathetic
10. resolution

I want to do an **online** search. I do not want to repeat this process multiple times, "the process: copypaste one word into search field and press enter, repeat, repeat again and again and again). I want the process to be less time consuming  e.g. "the hoped for process: copy all the words one time, do instantaneous online multiple/batch search". Is there a way to do that?

I am using Browser+Search Engine (Firefox, Brave and  Duckduckgo, Google).

I have searched online and I could find nothing helpful. There were pages describing how to do database "batch search", and I only assume they are not relevant to online search and those pages are too technical (for me).

Hopefully I will find an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that I take from W3School and it use the php "in_array" function and the essential HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$people = array("Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland"); <--this is the list of the name

if (in_array("Peter", $people)) <--this is the function that find the name "peter" in the list
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```